# Unable to get OpenLDAP admin ACL working

Tags: openldap

I have created a Posix group called Admins in my OpenLDAP domain and have added a user to it.

I have then added the following to my slapd.conf file

```
access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
    by dn="@ADMIN@" write
    by dn="cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=xxxxxxxxx,dc=xx,dc=uk" write
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by * none

access to dn.base=""
    by * read

access to *
    by dn="@ADMIN@" write
    by dn="cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx,dc=uk" write
    by * read
```

I have then created a user and added it to the admin group, but the user doesn't get the write permission I was expecting it to.

I am new to OpenLDAP and I am sure I have missed something obvious, but I don't seem to be able to find any answers on this site or others.

Comment: What do you mean by Posix group ? Could you tell us what is the complete list of objectClass for cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=xxxxxxxxx,dc=xx,dc=uk entry ?

Comment: It just says posixGroup under the objectClass

Answer (score 1):

Replace `by dn="cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com" write` with `by group.exact="cn=admin,ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com" write`.

Also, stop using `slapd.conf` and start using [`slapd-config`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html#Access%20Control%20via%20Dynamic%20Configuration). That way you don't have to restart your ldap server every time you make a change.

---

Also, if you're trying to add/remove an entry directly under the base suffix, you'll want to remove `access to dn.base="" by * read`.

Comment: Hi,

I have changed the configuration as suggested and I am still getting the error when I log in as a user in that group.

I am not sure why it isn't working, I would have thought this would be a simple thing to do! 

If I login as one of my accounts that is a member of the admin group using LDAP Admin the error says "Rights: No right access to parent".

Thank you for your help so far

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Retrieving members of posixGroup (eg to setting ACL)differs from retrieving them from groupOfNames.

To do this, check this [link content](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200803/msg00241.html) that deals with the same problem.

To effectively test the rights of the group, you should restrict ACLs to a single line like this:

```
access to * 
  by set="[cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=uk]/memberUid & user/uid" write 
  by users read 
  by anonymous auth
```

This access control gives write rights to group members, reading rights to other users and connecting rights to anonymous.

Of course this line is generally insufficient but this is an another subject.

Comment: Oh ok, that makes more sense! I tried to use the example in the link you provided, but that still doesn't seem to work. I have the following in my slapd.conf `access to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange
        by dn="@ADMIN@" write
        by set="user/uidNumber & [cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=uk]/memberUid"  write
        by anonymous auth
        by self write
        by * none
access to dn.base="" by * read

access to *
        by dn="@ADMIN@" write
        by set="user/uidNumber & [cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=uk]/memberUid"  write
        by * read`

Comment: First try this:

Comment: Try to remove all ACLs and keep only this one: access to * by set="[cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=uk]/memberUid & user/uid" write by * read. The ACLs work depends strongly on their order

Comment: thanks for your help so far, but still getting 0x32 (LDAP_INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS)

Comment: Sorry I forgot authentication rights for anonymous. Comment does not allow to write properly. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I use posix groups to manage the roles, and `set="[cn=Admins,ou=Groups,dc=xxx,dc=co,dc=uk]/memberUid & user/uid"` is the rescue!